# What's the most amount of attacks that can be done per turn with barbarian as a base?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, attack, barbarian

I'm thinking about DMing my first 5e campaign (I've GMed one *Pathfinder* one-off in the past).  A player of mine was thinking about playing a female orc Barbarian that specializes in dealing as many attacks in one turn as possible.

I was going to recommend a multiclass of Barbarian and Monk to make use of the *flurry of blows* from Monk: but I'm not quite sure.

**How does one make a Barbarian with the most amount of attacks per turn?**

Comment: Related: [What is the maximum number of attacks a single character can make themselves during their turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101655/33707)

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site. Can you specify what you mean by "using barbarian as a base"? Is 1 barbarian level enough, for example?

Comment: well um the player wants to play a barbarian so I guess atleast one or more levels while keeping the theme of a barbarian so probably no magic like quicken spell and stuff like that which is why I was thinking about recommending taking some levels in monk for the player.

Comment: Thank you for everyone helping out so far, I hope more people can help out as I'm not the best with character builds so having a variety of option might be helpful for my player, also um am I doing the questions and comment things right? I'm extremely new to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can accomplish *seven* attacks in a turn while still raging.

You mention you wanted to keep the theme of a barbarian, so I took that as you had to be able to employ the attacks during a Rage if available (i.e. no spells or concentration). With that restriction, your intuition to use monk is a solid one. The best build is as follows:

## The Character

Carlos is a level 20 character with the following classes:

- Barbarian (Path of the Berserker) 3 ----------- (for Rage and Frenzy)
- Monk (Way of the Drunken Master) 17 ------- (for Martial Arts, Ki, Extra Attack, and Intoxicated Frenzy)

## The Attacks

This build is intended to provide the most attacks throughout the career of the adventurer.

Now, Carlos *can* use any weapon and still get unarmed strikes from Flurry of Blows, but they will not get the extra attack dice unless he is wielding a monk weapon. Picking up the Tavern Brawler feat (perhaps as a Human (Variant)) mitigates this somewhat, but doesn't help when the attack dice starts to get larger as Carlos progresses as a monk.

Initially, Carlos acquires his barbarian identity with the best Primal Path for attacks:

### Levels 3-7

At these levels, Carlos can benefit from the Ki feature to use Flurry of Blows allowing for these attacks:

- Attack action with a weapon
- Bonus action unarmed strike x2

When Carlos no longer has ki points, he can use Frenzy to give access to these attacks

- Attack action with a weapon
- Bonus action attack with a weapon

If Carlos lacks rages *and* ki, he can switch to a monk weapon to benefit from Martial Arts for these attacks:

- Attack action with a monk weapon
- Bonus action unarmed strike

### Levels 8-19

These levels are mostly dedicated to helping Carlos acquire more ki points, so he can use Flurry of Blows more often. In addition, he picks up Extra Attack at level 8, which while it is a little delayed, does give him an extra attack. Here's his attacks while he has ki points:

- Attack action with a weapon x2
- Bonus action unarmed strike x2

When out of ki points in Frenzy:

- Attack action with a weapon x2
- Bonus action attack with a weapon

When out of rages and ki points:

- Attack action with a monk weapon x2
- Bonus action unarmed strike

### Level 20

Finally, you reach this characters capstone potential where the Intoxicated Frenzy allows for seven attacks:

- Attack action with a weapon x2
- Bonus action unarmed strike x5 (against different targets)

This is only possible when ki points are available, but with 7 ki points between rests, Carlos can use Flurry of Blows quite often.

### Magic Items

Few magic items help a lot with extra attacks. However, Carlos may be interested in picking up a *scimitar of speed* which will allow for a more powerful attack than the Martial Arts option when out of ki points and frenzy:

> You gain a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. In addition, you can make one attack with it as a bonus action on each of your turns.

A scimitar, however, is not a monk weapon meaning you will not benefit from Martial Arts's benefit to unarmed strikes when using it in other attack-sequences (such as when using Flurry of Blows).