# How many melee attacks can a character make on turn one in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack

I once spent close to 8 hours doing in-depth research on all the subclasses available to find this out for a level 12 character, and managed to find a build that could make 14 attacks on turn 1 without any magical items.
Unfortunately, this was also 2-3 years ago, and I can't remember most of the details, other than there was some fighter and ranger in it.
Can anyone help me figure out a version of this for a level 20 character?

Comment: Related, possibly contains the answer to your question: [What is the maximum number of attacks a single character can make during their turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101655/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-attacks-a-single-character-can-make-themselves-dur)